# Glossaries, exclude part (pages) from being indexed (such as list of tables)

Tags: glossaries

I use glossaries, i.e. I have `\usepackage[toc,nopostdot]{glossaries}` and `\makeglossaries` in my Latex file, and a couple of definitions like

```
\newacronym[
description={\Glsentrylong{asr}. The conversion from speech-to-text by automatic means.}
]{asr}{ASR}{automatic speech recognition}
```

Later in my Latex file, I have `\printglossary[title={Glossary}]`.

After `pdflatex`, I call `makeglossaries`, and then `pdflatex` again.

That all works fine.

Then later I also have this:

```
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

In some of the table/figure captions, I also use some of the acronyms (e.g. `\gls{asr}`). That also works. However, the same caption is also present in the list of figures and list of tables at the end.

When `\printglossary` lists all the page numbers, it also lists the page numbers of the list of figures and list of tables.

Can I avoid that? I.e. skip some part of the Latex file from not being indexed, i.e. not being part of the page number listing of the glossaries? Specifically, I want to exclude the list of figures and list of tables. How?

Comment: I have the same problem, does anyone have any updates on how to reset it again, since all the main matter is also excluded from the acronym list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found the solution while skimming through [the documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf).

You can add this somewhere into the Latex file:

```
\renewcommand*{\glswriteentry}[2]{}
```

From that point on, no GLS entries will be indexed anymore.
(I'm not exactly sure how to re-enable it again, but I don't need that for now. I'm also not sure whether that is the best solution, but it seems to work.)